# Bootstrap add section after iframe

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very simple Bootstrap with two full screen sections:

```
<!-- Intro Header -->
<header class="intro">
    <div class="intro-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h1 class="brand-heading">Roald Dahl</h1>
                    <p class="intro-text">100th anniversary of Roald Dahl's birth
                        <br>World's No.1 storyteller</p>
                    <a href="#timeline" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<!-- About Section -->
<section id="timeline" class="container-fluid content-section">
    <div class="row">
<iframe src='http://roalddahl.tk/TMcompiled/timeline.html' style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; border:0px solid lightgrey;" frameborder='1'></iframe>
    </div>
</section>
```

I want to add one more section after the iframe, like this:

```
<section id="bibliography" class="container content-section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="download-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <h2>Download Grayscale</h2>
                <p>You can download Grayscale for free on the preview page at Start Bootstrap.</p>
                <a href="http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/grayscale/" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Visit Download Page</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The problem is all the content from my third section goes in to the iframe section just below the intro on top of the ifarme content instead of below it.

Some CSS:

```
}
.intro {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 100px 0;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background: url(../img/intro-bg.jpg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
  background-color: pink;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
.intro .intro-body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.colorcolor {
    background-color: red;
}
.content-section {
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  height: auto;
}
```

My third section is unable to see my iframe properly and places everything just below the intro but I'm not sure how to make it work.
Is it any way to add next section where it should be without modifying my iframe secton?

Comment: Provide a phpfiddle or codepan link with your code and the issue, then we will be able to provide you a better solution.

Comment: This sections mismatch is caused by the "position: absolute" property of the iframe. When removed from the style the sections are in order one above the other. Unfortunately I need this property so I combine with "height: 100%" to achieve full screen cover effect for the iframe.

Comment: I have tried your code in jsfiddle, but didn't encounter your mentioned issue. That's why asking you to provide a fiddle that has the issue on it.

Comment: Hello Arif. Unfortunately I can't provide fiddle nor any link to the website. I'll try to fix the issue by removing the "position: absolute" property.

Comment: Solved. The issue was resolved by adding "position: absolute" property to the next section as well.  .download-section {position: absolute;}

Comment: Great... Glad to hear about this :)